# I have an error using TimestampedGeoJson in folium

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I'm trying to use `TimestampedGeoJson` from `Folium`. But it doesn't work.
My goal is to visualize the route by entering the latitude and longitude values in `TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO`.
However, the following error occurred: 
I searched a lot of data in stackoverflow, but I don't think it fits my case. to be in need of assistance
`TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO` is an array with a latitude value.

---

for n in geo_df.index:

```
lines = [
{
    'coordinates': [
        [TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[0:,0], TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[0,0:]],
        [TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[1:,0], TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[0,1:]],
    ],
    'dates': [
        '2017-06-02T00:00:00',
        '2017-06-02T00:10:00'
    ],
    'color': 'red'
},
]

features = [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': line['coordinates'],
        },
        'properties': {
            'times': line['dates'],
            'style': {
                'color': line['color'],
                'weight': line['weight'] if 'weight' in line else 5
            }
        }
    }
    for line in lines
]

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson({
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': features,
}, period='PT1M', add_last_point=True).add_to(map)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        40     'type': 'FeatureCollection',
>        41     'features': features,
>   ---> 42 }, period='PT1M', add_last_point=True).add_to(map)
>
> TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a numpy.ndarray as an input and, like the error message shows, this is not accepted. You can simply change the coordinate input to:

```
'coordinates': [
    [TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[0][0], TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[0][1]],
    [TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[1][0], TYP_LOCATION_MATRIX_FLO[1][1]],
],
```

and this should do the trick as you are now passing values instead of arrays.